# regex include all until closed html tag

Tags: javascript, python, regex

for example i have this content:

```
<p>first line</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ifelse id="df950c19-e3f6-4e14-872b-d73a78e17f8e" typ="ifelse" value="">
<p>Example text</p>
<p><var-input id="80585bab-49a4-4841-b87c-1e004c1a31d1" typ="textzeile" value="" class="mceNonEditable">Textzeile</var-input> ...</p>
</ifelse>
<p>Another ifelse tag</p>
<ifelse id="1199fc18-1f12-4483-b81c-94c8945e6390" typ="ifelse" value="">
<p>This is an <strong>example</strong></p>
</ifelse>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I have a problem to get the content between the opened and closed `ifelse` tag because this content can include any character also newline and so on. At the moment this regex works good if i have only one element of `<ifelse ..>...</ifelse>`:

```
<ifelse id="(?<id>[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})" typ="(?:.*)" value="(?:.*)">(?<content>[\s\S\w\W\d\D]*)<\/ifelse>
```

But with two or more `ifelse` elements the regex matches the full content between the first opened tag and the last closed tag.

How can i solve this?

In the end i would like to use the regex in JavaScript and Python.

Comment: seach for "non-greedy regexp"

Comment: How about `<ifelse.*?</ifelse>` ?

Comment: That not match new line (terminators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lazy operator `?` to select the smallest matches, and then use the `g` flag to perform a global search:

```js
const content = `
<p>first line</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ifelse id="df950c19-e3f6-4e14-872b-d73a78e17f8e" typ="ifelse" value="">
<p>Example text</p>
<p><var-input id="80585bab-49a4-4841-b87c-1e004c1a31d1" typ="textzeile" value="" class="mceNonEditable">Textzeile</var-input> ...</p>
</ifelse>
<p>Another ifelse tag</p>
<ifelse id="1199fc18-1f12-4483-b81c-94c8945e6390" typ="ifelse" value="">
<p>This is an <strong>example</strong></p>
</ifelse>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
`;

// * -> *?, using global flag
const regex = /<ifelse id="(?<id>[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})" typ="(?:.*)" value="(?:.*)">(?<content>[\s\S\w\W\d\D]*?)<\/ifelse>/g;
console.log(content.match(regex));
```

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) for Python, you can view this example on **[repl.it](https://repl.it/@christiantjl/ExoticPaltryDos#main.py)**.